# wordpress, I cannot find where redirects are defined

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I can't understand where 301 redirects are defined on my WordPress site. there is nothing in the htaccess file, just as there are no plugins. the only thing i can say is that i uninstalled a seo redirection 301 plugin which contained the redirects. I wonder how they can still be present after uninstalling, cleaning the cache of the browser and the purge the sg optimizer. I also tried to install the plugin again to try to recover the redirects in order to delete them but there is no trace. Help

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to Settings -> Permalinks. Hit Save Changes button. Then try to check in incognito mode.

Comment: Can you share the link which is getting redirected?

Comment: https://www.datalog.it/fatture is the url that is redirected 301 and I don't understand where this redirection come from

Comment: Try installing the plugin again and clear cache from plugin settings and then check.

Comment: hello I installed again but no clear cache there, or how can I clear cache? do you know that plugin?

Comment: Check the database many plugins leave their tables there after deleting them

Comment: checked,  plugins tables are empty

Comment: What about server-side redirects? They could be listed in a .conf file, for example, though they can be set in a number of different ways - apparently. I've never tried it, but I have run into an example of the .conf file variety.